# Determine the dimensions. Prepare to exam

Tags: linear-algebra

Can someone show me how should I solve this exercise I need just a 1 example then i will try myself.

Determine the dimensions of LIN(S) ∩ LIN(T) and LIN(S) + LIN(T) for

(1) S = {(1, 2, 0, 1),(1, 1, 1, 0)}, T = {(1, 0, 1, 0),(1, 3, 0, 1)};

(2) S = {(1, 1, 1, 1),(1, −1, 1, −1),(1, 3, 1, 3)}, T = {(1, 2, 0, 2),(1, 2, 1, 2),(3, 1, 3, 1)};

(3) S = {(2, −1, 0, −2)(3, −2, 1, 0),(1, −1, 1, −1)}, T = {(3, −1, −1, 0),(0, −1, 2, 3),(5, −2, −1, 0)}.

In each case give any basis of LIN(S) + LIN(T).

Can someone give me some advice?

LIN = span

Comment: What's LIN?  The span?

Comment: @yeah lin is the span

Comment: For each exercise find the rank of the matrices obtained by stacking all the vectors belonging to the base sets and then use the null+rank theorem.

Comment: @N74 For example I calculate rank of (1) rank=3  but could you explain me what is null theorem?

Comment: You can read it here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank–nullity_theorem

Comment: @N74 ok so have  rank(1)=3 and nullity1)=1 what thats give us? We wantDetermine the dimensions of LIN(S) ∩ LIN(T) and LIN(S) + LIN(T) and then calculate base of  LIN(S) + LIN(T).

Comment: @tilper could u tell me what i have to do in this task?

Comment: $rank(span(S))=rank(span(T))=2$, $rank(span(S)+span(T))=3<4$ so there's a subspace shared by the two subspaces, whose dimension is  $rank(span(S))+rank(span(T))-rank(span(S)+span(T))$

Comment: @N74 ok,  LIN(S) + LIN(T)= 3 LIN(S) ∩ LIN(T)= 1 for first example and the base is for example base of LIN(S) + LIN(T) is{(1, 2, 0, 1),(1, 1, 1, 0),(1, 0, 1, 0)}. That is correct?

Comment: Seems good to me as $(1,3,0,1)=(1,2,0,1)+(1,1,1,0)-(1,0,1,0)$

Comment: @N74  This is good right LIN(S) + LIN(T)= 3?  But that should be    LIN(S) ∩ LIN(T)= 2 or LIN(S) ∩ LIN(T)= 1 i think 2 is correct i have right?

Comment: For the first exercise the intersection cannot have the same dimension of the two base subspaces, otherwise the two subspaces must be equal.